# Traefik 2.x and GitLab Docker Setup Returning 404 for GitLab Service

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, traefik

I've set up GitLab using Docker and Traefik 2.11 as a reverse proxy, but when I try to access GitLab at https://gitlab.example.com, I get a 404 error. I'm using Docker Compose for both Traefik and GitLab configurations. Traefik is supposed to handle HTTPS requests and route them to GitLab, but it seems like the routing isn't working as expected.

```
version: '3'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.11
    container_name: "traefik"
    restart: always
    command:
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedByDefault=false"
      - "--providers.docker.network=traefik_web"
      - "--entrypoints.http.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.http.http.redirections.entrypoint.to=https"
      - "--entrypoints.http.http.redirections.entrypoint.scheme=https"
      - "--entrypoints.https.address=:443"
      - "--entrypoints.https.http.tls.certResolver=le"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.le.acme.tlschallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.le.acme.email=deine@mail.de"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.le.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./../letsencrypt:/letsencrypt
    networks:
      - web

networks:
  web:
    name: traefik_web
```

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  gitlab-main:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
    hostname: "gitlab.skull-music.com"
    container_name: gitlab
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        external_url 'https://gitlab.skull-music.com'
    networks:
      - traefik_web
    labels:
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.gitlab.rule=Host(`gitlab.skull-music.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.gitlab.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.gitlab.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.gitlab.service=gitlab-main"
      - "traefik.http.services.gitlab-main.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
      - "traefik.http.routers.gitlab.tls.certResolver=le"


networks:
  traefik_web:
    name: traefik_web
    external: true
```

What I've tried:

1. Ensuring DNS settings are correct.
2. Checking Traefik and GitLab logs, but there are no obvious errors related to the 404.
3. Verifying that the Traefik network `traefik_web` is correctly shared between Traefik and GitLab services.
4. I added the line like suggested in the answers.

```
      - "traefik.http.routers.gitlab.tls.certResolver=le"
```

**Questions:**

Is there any misconfiguration in my Docker Compose files that could be causing this issue?
How can I further debug the 404 error when accessing GitLab through Traefik?
Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Gitlab seems to take a damn long time to even start. Have you tried debugging with an image like `nginx:latest`? I tested your service labels with that image, and it works for me, so the issue is then either with the gitlab image needing something extra or with the configuration of your traefik container. Edit: Also test without https first if that works or not.

Comment: nginx, minio, heimdall and traefik dashboard works fine. each one over https. finally after 15 minutes the container crashed do to problem with letsencrypt_certificate. i think thats a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a `certResolver` from your service labels. You have this on your traefik command, but it needs to be included on the `gitlab-main` service too, like this:

```
      - "traefik.http.routers.gitlab.tls.certResolver=le"
```

From [Traefik Documentation](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/https/acme/#certificate-resolvers)

> Defining a certificate resolver does not result in all routers automatically using it. Each router that is supposed to use the resolver must reference it.

I tested on my own server, and without it I get the same `404` error.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, after applying the changes you recommended, I'm still facing issues getting everything to work as expected.
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.gitlab.rule=Host(`gitlab.skull-music.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.gitlab.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.gitlab.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.gitlab.service=gitlab-main"
      - "traefik.http.services.gitlab-main.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
      - "traefik.http.routers.gitlab.tls.certResolver=le"

Comment: Please also edit the original question with the changes and possible new problems.

Comment: I edited it. i changed the domain name back to the correct one in case this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the lines nginx['listen_https'] = false and nginx['listen_port'] = 80 to the docker-copmpose.yml file effectively resolved my issue.

Without it the container stopped working after some time do to a RuntimeError related to acme_certificate.

Also i want mention that gitlab takes a while to start (in the case till it crashed 10 minutes)

```
version: '3.7'
services:

  gitlab-main:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
    hostname: "gitlab.skull-music.com"
    container_name: gitlab
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        external_url 'https://gitlab.skull-music.com'
        nginx['listen_https'] = false
        nginx['listen_port'] = 80
    networks:
      - traefik_web
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.gitlab.rule=Host(`gitlab.skull-music.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.gitlab.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.gitlab.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.gitlab.service=gitlab-main"
      - "traefik.http.services.gitlab-main.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
      - "traefik.http.routers.gitlab.tls.certResolver=le"

networks:
  traefik_web:
    name: traefik_web
    external: true
```